# How to identify favourite products in cordova

Tags: cordova

I am developing one app using cordova. In that i am listing products and providing favorite icon for each product. When user click on favourite icon, i have to store that information some where but not in db. In case user navigate to same product after some time, i should indicate favourite icon in different color.

Where do i save favourite product information?

I thought to store product id in session. But i realised that is not the right approach when selected products count get increase.

Please help me to solve this scenario.

Comment: Please check local storage or sqlite..

Comment: Thanks you. I will try.

Comment: May i know, why down voted?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin. https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage it will solve your problem bro.

Cheers